# Razor htmlListBox helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedClients, new SelectList(Model.allClients, "ClientId", "Name"))
```

The above code refer to the Razor html helper for HTML List box.

How to set the size=20 in the above code?

Comment: `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedClients, new SelectList(....), new { size = "20" })`

Comment: Thank you. You answered my question. I was adding "new size" code under new select and it was not working. Thank you. Select as answer button is disabled for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.ListBoxFor<code>2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B</code>0%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B<code>0,</code>1%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.Object%29) that accepts `htmlAttributes`

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedClients, new SelectList(....), new { size = "20" })
```